# Cannot find colorscheme in neovim

Tags: vimscript, neovim, plugin-vim-plug

I am a very very new user of neovim and i was trying to customize it using `init.vim`. When i was trying to set a color theme for neovim, it did not work. I am using vim-plug and i have the plugin in the `plugged` folder. Here is my code in the init.vim file:

```
set number

call plug#begin('C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\nvim\autoload\plugged')
Plug 'navarasu/onedark.nvim'
colorscheme onedark
call plug#end()
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think you want to put `colorscheme onedark` after `call plug#end()`.

Comment: The  coment of @Martin is very valid but did you o  top ran the `:PluInstall` command and restart `Vim`?

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thanks! that works. Can you post an answer so i can mark it as the answer?